# How to make IntelliJ find my repository beans?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javabeans

I have a Spring project and the following Maven project structure :

```
Parent project
  - commons
  - application1
  - application2
```

In commons I have some models and repositories ( CrudRepository if that matters ) and in application1 I have a service that uses that repository.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    // methods that use the repository

}
```

Now, everything works perfectly, the code compiles and runs as expected but IntelliJ keeps telling me it can't autowire the bean because it can't find it.

This is the exact message:

> Could not autowire. No beans of type "MyRepository" type found.

What is wrong with IntelliJ here? What can I do for it to see those classes from the commons project?

Comment: Have you [configured the spring facet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/spring.html) to include all your spring configuration classes a/o files (`File` -> `Project structure` -> `Facets` -> `Spring`)?

Comment: Awesome. I have added the repositories as Code Bsed Configurations and now InteliJ looks happy. Thank you very much.